# Telerik testing tools - escape ampersand (&) in search string

Tags: telerik, automated-tests, telerik-testing-tools

I'm using the [Telerik Testing Tools](http://www.telerik.com/automated-testing-tools/).  My goal is to wait for an anchor to make it to the screen, then click on it.  The anchor has an href of `#resources/details?mode=view&resourceId=149176`

I'm having problems escaping that string properly.  This code **works perfectly**:

```
ActiveBrowser.WaitForElement(5000, "href=~resourceId=149176")
             .As<HtmlAnchor>().Click();
```

Unfortunately, when I try to incorporate more of the url, it breaks, ie, this does not work

```
ActiveBrowser.WaitForElement(5000, "href=~view&resourceId=149176")
             .As<HtmlAnchor>().Click();
```

It seems as though the `&` is the problem.  I've tried escaping it with everything I can think of based on [Telerik's documentation on find expressions](http://www.telerik.com/automated-testing-tools/support/documentation/user-guide/write-tests-in-code/intermediate-topics/element-identification/find-expressions.aspx), including `\` `\'` and `=`.

What is the proper way to escape this string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that you can use `&amp` for this one.